# how can i export to Standard excel file from jasper with the image and cell border and the excel file look likes normal excel file?

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports, ireport, export-to-excel

I am using jasper report to export my excel report in my liferay custom portlet JSP Page.

now what happen is when i set IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS property false then its showing image in excel report.but then the column of excel report not showing any border..and if i set it to true then its not showing image and then every column comes with border..now what i want is both as image on the excel report as well as the cell border of the excel report.

following is my jrxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="RestaurantReport" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="520" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isFloatColumnFooter="true">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.1000000000000032"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.graphics" value="false"/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Table Dataset 1"/>
    <field name="advertisename" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="camp_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ad_location" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="clicked" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="impression" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="filter_start_date" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <field name="filter_end_date" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <field name="ctr" class="java.lang.Float"/>
    <field name="restaurantname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="medianame" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="RestaurantTotal" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Restaurant Name" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{impression}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="RestaurantGrandTotal" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{impression}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="CTR Total" class="java.lang.Float" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Restaurant Name" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{ctr}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="CTRGrandtotal" class="java.lang.Float" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{ctr}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="ClickTotal" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{clicked}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="ClickGrandTotal" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Restaurant Name" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{clicked}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="Restaurant Name" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{restaurantname}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="30" width="149" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#0FAAC2"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                        <paragraph firstLineIndent="4"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Advertise Name]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="412" y="30" width="46" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#0FAAC2"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Click]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="283" y="30" width="78" height="20" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#0FAAC2"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                        <paragraph firstLineIndent="2"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[AD Location]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="458" y="30" width="51" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#0FAAC2"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Impression]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="284" height="20"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Restaurant Name : "+ $F{restaurantname}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="149" y="30" width="134" height="20" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#0FAAC2"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                        <paragraph firstLineIndent="4"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Campaign]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="509" y="30" width="46" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#0FAAC2"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[CTR (%)]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="361" y="30" width="51" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#0FAAC2"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                        <paragraph firstLineIndent="4" leftIndent="10"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Type]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="21">
                <textField pattern="###0.00">
                    <reportElement x="509" y="1" width="47" height="20"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ClickTotal}/$V{RestaurantTotal}*100]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="412" y="0" width="46" height="21"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ClickTotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="270" y="1" width="142" height="20"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="true"/>
                        <paragraph leftIndent="5"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Group Total ]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="458" y="1" width="51" height="20"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{RestaurantTotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="113">
            <image scaleImage="RetainShape" isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement x="414" y="0" width="139" height="65"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Liferay\\tomcat-7.0.27\\webapps\\eMenuAdvertise-portlet\\img\\eMenuLogo.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField pattern="MM/dd/yyyy h.mm a Z">
                <reportElement x="30" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="30" y="93" width="64" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{filter_start_date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Date : ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="94" y="93" width="19" height="20"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[To:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="93" width="30" height="20"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[From:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="113" y="93" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{filter_end_date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="130" y="23" width="283" height="67"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="16" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Restaurant Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="18" splitType="Immediate">
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="1" width="149" height="15"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single" firstLineIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{advertisename}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="283" y="1" width="78" height="15" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single" firstLineIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ad_location}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="458" y="1" width="51" height="15"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{impression}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="412" y="1" width="46" height="15"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{clicked}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line direction="BottomUp">
                <reportElement x="0" y="16" width="555" height="1"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="149" y="1" width="134" height="15"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9"/>
                    <paragraph firstLineIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{camp_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="509" y="1" width="46" height="15"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ctr}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="361" y="1" width="51" height="15"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9"/>
                    <paragraph firstLineIndent="5" leftIndent="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{medianame}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="23" splitType="Immediate">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="226" y="0" width="80" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="308" y="0" width="40" height="20"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <lastPageFooter>
        <band height="20" splitType="Immediate">
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="308" y="0" width="40" height="20"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="228" y="0" width="80" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </lastPageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="257" y="0" width="155" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                    <paragraph rightIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Grand Total]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="###0" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement x="458" y="0" width="51" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{RestaurantGrandTotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="###0.00">
                <reportElement x="509" y="0" width="45" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ClickGrandTotal}/$V{RestaurantGrandTotal}*100]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="###0">
                <reportElement x="412" y="0" width="46" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ClickGrandTotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
    <noData>
        <band/>
    </noData>
</jasperReport>
```

these is the properties i set before exporting to excel file

```
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,
                jasperPrint);
        exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,
                byteArrayOutputStream);
        exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_CELL_BORDER,
                Boolean.FALSE);
        exporterXLS.setParameter(
                JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporterXLS.setParameter(
                JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS,
                Boolean.TRUE);
        exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN,
                Boolean.TRUE);
        exporterXLS.setParameter(
                JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS,
                Boolean.TRUE);
        exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET,
                Boolean.FALSE);
        exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE,
                Boolean.FALSE);

        exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS,
                Boolean.FALSE);
```

So can Anyone Please guide me that **how can i export to Standard excel file from jasper with the image cell border and the excel file look likes normal excel file.**other problem is that **its not even coming in proper alignment**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the Above Function i have set all parameter thats helps me to achieve this..posting this for the people who have still problems to export excel file with jasper.thanx

```
  private void SetExcelReportParameter(JRXlsExporter exporterXLS,
                JasperPrint jasperPrint, ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream) {

            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,
                    jasperPrint);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,
                    byteArrayOutputStream);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_CELL_BORDER,
                    Boolean.FALSE);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(
                    JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(
                    JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS,
                    Boolean.TRUE);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN,
                    Boolean.TRUE);

            exporterXLS.setParameter(
                    JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS,
                    Boolean.TRUE);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET,
                    Boolean.FALSE);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE,
                    Boolean.TRUE);

            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IMAGE_BORDER_FIX_ENABLED,
                    Boolean.TRUE);
            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_FONT_SIZE_FIX_ENABLED,
                    Boolean.TRUE);

            exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS,
                    Boolean.FALSE);

        }
```